# Why does pandas.read_json() returns an empty dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

My problem is quite straightforward.

I have the following json string: 
`myjson = '{"resolves_to": "16534af166355cda", "aliases": []}'`
that I want to convert to a DataFrame using `pd.read_json(myjson)`, but instead of returning a DataFrame with one row and two columns (*resolves_to* and *aliases*), with an empty entry in the column *aliases* (which is what I need), it returns an empty DataFrame.

I would like to understand why, and how to get the DataFrame I need.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it a list:

```
myjson = '[{"resolves_to": "16534af166355cda", "aliases": []}]'
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json(myjson)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I also saw that there is an argument 'lines' to the function, that if set to True seems to perform the same thing.